# How to tell which type of object i want to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting this json via ajax:

```
[{"currency_value":"1.00","currency_code":"47","type":"BUY"},{"currency_value":"1.00","currency_code":"47","type":"SELL"}]
```

However i want to use only the one who has the type of "SELL"

```
 var setcurrencyvalue = function(to, value) {
    parseInt($(to).attr('value', value)); // set the currency val
    calculatetotal();
    $('.amount-remaining').val(0);
    //set the amount
}

var showcurval = function(cur_code) {
    var $curcode = '';
    var $currency = $('.currency-czk');
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url:  '/transactions/get_currency_val?cur_code=' + cur_code,
       success: function(data) {
           var obj = JSON.parse(data);
           $.each(obj, function (k, v) {
             //  console.log(v);
               switch (v.currency_code) {
                   case '47':
                       $curcode = '€'; // 1
                       setcurrencyvalue($currency, v.currency_value);
                       break;
                   case '33':
                       $curcode = 'Kč'; // CZK/EUR
                       setcurrencyvalue($currency, v.currency_value);
                       break;
                   case '131':
                       $curcode = '₽'; //CZK/RUB
                       setcurrencyvalue($currency, v.currency_value);
                       break;
                   case '144':
                       $curcode = '$'; //CZK/USD
                       setcurrencyvalue($currency, v.currency_value);
                       break;
                   case '168':
                       alert('Please set a currency!');
                       break;
               }

           });

       }
    });
}
```

This will give me the the `v.currency_value` randomly there are two of them. how to tell Ajax to work only with "SELL" or "BUY"?

Comment: If this is an ajax issue you need to check up the api, we don't know what that is. Otherwise it's your code at fault.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the data you get per AJAX.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var sells = obj.filter(function(a) {
    return a.type === "SELL";
});
```

This will return new array only with the objects that have the value SELL in their attribute type.

Here is also a link to the array method filter:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

Just [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the data when it's returned:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data).filter(function (el) {
  return el.type === 'SELL';
})[0]; // { currency_value: "1.00", currency_code: "47", type: "SELL" }
```

`filter` returns an array. The `[0]` returns the first element of the array. Leave it off if you have more than one object with `type: 'SELL'` that you need to be returned.

If you wanted to have a generalised function to get objects by type from the data it might look like this:

```
function getDataByType(data, type) {
    return data.filter(function (el) {
        return el.type === type;
    });
}

var arr = getDataByType(data, 'SELL');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/baccec6u/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the resulting array just after having parsed it.
Basically its about using the filter prototype:

```
obj.filter(function (el) {
     return el.type === "SELL"
});
```

As a result you get a new array which only contains the elements that pass the filter-function.

For more information on filtering JS-Arrays see this one:

[Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Cheers, Kristof

Comment: You should probably call `obj` `arr` instead to save confusion.

Comment: This is the original name of the OP :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a if condition like this

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url:  '/transactions/get_currency_val?cur_code=' + cur_code,
   success: function(data) {
       var obj = JSON.parse(data);
       $.each(obj, function (k, v) {
         //  console.log(v);
         if(v.type == "SELL"){
           switch (v.currency_code) {
               case '47':
                   $curcode = '€'; // 1
                   setcurrencyvalue($currency, v.currency_value);
                   break;
               case '33':
                   $curcode = 'Kč'; // CZK/EUR
                   setcurrencyvalue($currency, v.currency_value);
                   break;
               case '131':
                   $curcode = '₽'; //CZK/RUB
                   setcurrencyvalue($currency, v.currency_value);
                   break;
               case '144':
                   $curcode = '$'; //CZK/USD
                   setcurrencyvalue($currency, v.currency_value);
                   break;
               case '168':
                   alert('Please set a currency!');
                   break;
           }
         }
       });

   }
});
```